# Am I using parse right?

Tags: java, parsing, joptionpane

As far as I can tell i'm doing this right ( Clearly not though )
I am trying to change strings into Doubles because I can't get a double from a JPane. it is giving me an object not initialized error. How do I fix it?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class jwindows {
    public static void main (String args[]) {

        double a, b, c;
        double sum = a + b + c;
        double product = a * b * c ;
        double avarge = a * b * c / 3;

    String stringA = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
            (null, "Please enter first number");
        a = Double.parseDouble(stringA);

    String stringB = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
            (null, "Please enter second number: ");
        b = Double.parseDouble(stringB);

    String stringC = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
            (null, "Please enter third number: ");  
        c = Double.parseDouble(stringC);

        JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog
        (null, "The sum of the 3 numbers is " + sum);

        JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog
        (null, "The avarge of the 3 numbers is " + avarge);

        JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog
        (null, "The sum of the 3 numbers is " + product);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the exact error?

Comment: If you are not getting NumberFormatException then you are parsing right.

Comment: a,b, and c have not need assigned to anything when you try to compute sum average and product. Move those definitions until after you parse c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double a, b, c;
double sum = a + b + c;
double product = a * b * c ;
double avarge = a * b * c / 3;
```

You just defined variables, but didn't initialize them. Move them below right after all values for a, b, c obtained.

One more thing: Change `showInternalMessageDialog` to `showMessageDialog` as you don't have parent component at all.

Comment: Thanks mate, I was actually just about to ask why I wasn't getting boxes. Saved me some trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

The variables `a`, `b`, `c` have not been initialized (and do not contain any value) and so `sum`, `product` and `avarage` cannot be calculated. To fix this, just move `sum`, `product` and `avarge` until after you've parsed `a`, `b`, `c`. Like this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class jwindows {
public static void main (String args[]) {
double a, b, c;

String stringA = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter first number");
a = Double.parseDouble(stringA);

String stringB = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter second number: ");
b = Double.parseDouble(stringB);

String stringC = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter third number: ");  
c = Double.parseDouble(stringC);

double sum = a + b + c;
double product = a * b * c ;
double avarge = a * b * c / 3;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The sum of the 3 numbers is " + sum);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The avarge of the 3 numbers is " + avarge);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The sum of the 3 numbers is " + product);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wont get the expected value for the variables **sum, averge and product.** You are calculating its value in the beginning :

```
double a, b, c;
double sum = a + b + c;
double product = a * b * c ;
double avarge = a * b * c / 3;
```

You must get compilation error over here because, a,b and c are local variables which are not initialized before using them. So compiler will throw error in such cases.
Even if the are initialized to some value, you must calculate values for sum, averge and prodcut after you assign value to these variables from showInputDialog.

try using this :

```
sum = a+b+c;

     JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog
    (null, "The sum of the 3 numbers is " + sum);

     averge = (a+b+c)/3;
    JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog
    (null, "The avarge of the 3 numbers is " + avarge);
    product = a*b*c;
    JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog
    (null, "The sum of the 3 numbers is " + product);
```